# Input is not defined in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, input, ng-template

I want to implement something using ngTemplate and I'm following [this example](https://medium.com/@akoserwal/nginclude-to-ng-template-12cb87880a14).

The problem I'm facing appears when the @input is added:

```
import { Component, OnInit, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.css']
})


export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
   ...
   @Input() headingTemplate: TemplateRef<any>; 

}
```

When it is saved it shows this error message in console:

> my.component.ts:13 Uncaught ReferenceError: Input is not defined
>       at Module../src/app/my/my.component.ts (my.component.ts:13)

Why is this happening and how can it be solved? I even found the file on [their github](https://github.com/patternfly/patternfly-ng/blob/master/src/app/notification/notification-drawer/notification-drawer.component.ts) project and still no idea. Could be a problem because I'm using Angular 8?

Comment: Please accept Sajeetharan's answer as he posted the same answer few seconds before mine

Comment: I cannot understand why this is considered off-topic.
I came looking for an answer to the same problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the import

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
```